# List of port numbers used on default installations

Tags: port

I realise that it would be a bit 'volatile', but I can't find a list of port numbers and the applications or services that would use them by default.

Sometimes seeing javaw.exe just isn't good enough :)

Note: To see the ports in use on a Windows OS machine, use `netstat` at the command line or download [TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) for example.

Thanks

Additional question.  Can an application use a range of ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the list of officially registered ports you can look on [IANA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority).

http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers

> Can an application use a range of
>   ports?

Absolutely.  For example SIP, or H.323 typically have half a dozen different connections open at the same time for all the content streams and control streams.  FTP uses at least two and occasionally more ports.

Answer (score 1):

On a non-windows system,

```
cat /etc/services
```

Will show the IANA registered names for ports. Of course, this doesn't really tell you which applications will use which ports, but it at least gives you a hint about what ports mught be used. For example, your email application will likely use one or more of the following: smtp, pop3, imap, pop3s, imaps.